# Getting blank page when running (In Debug Mode) Flutter project on Crome after linking with Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase

I was frequently testing my project on Crome but things changed when I linked it with Firebase. After linking, I am able to run it on my device smoothly but getting blank page on Crome or any other browser.

I have already made the required changes in index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A platform to publish notes and study matterials">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="notes">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>notes</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function(ev) {
      // Download main.dart.js
      _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
        serviceWorker: {
          serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
        },
        onEntrypointLoaded: function(engineInitializer) {
          engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function(appRunner) {
            appRunner.runApp();
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script type="module">
  import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-app.js";
  import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.19.1/firebase-analytics.js";
  const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDGt9nNCr2QCX8ZnZdzFBDj6oalswhSVHU",
    authDomain: "notes-77d93.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "notes-77d93",
    storageBucket: "notes-77d93.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "925320174988",
    appId: "1:925320174988:web:e280f6d68f3ea5833e8aa9",
    measurementId: "G-G26HN95CV0"
  };

  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```